# Sync buttons with Materialize css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, positioning, materialize

I'm using Materialize CSS (close to bootstrap) and I have two columns with text and both have a button in the bottom of the column. However because the content size of both columns are of different sizes, the buttons aren't on the same height. (see picture)

I could set them straight with the use of margin, but I'd rather not to.

Anyone has a other solution?

[image: sync button with materialize css]

It doesn't seem to work with me, here is the full code. maybe you can find something I did wrong.

```css
body {
    background-image: url("../images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

nav {
    padding-left: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* label focus color */
.input-field input[type=password]:focus + label {
    color: #ee6e73;
}
/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=password]:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee6e73;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ee6e73;
}

/* label focus color */
.input-field input[type=email]:focus + label {
    color: #ee6e73;
}
/* label underline focus color */
.input-field input[type=email]:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ee6e73;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ee6e73;
}

.input-field button {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.input-field button:hover {
    background-color: #ee6e73;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
}

.container .section {
    background-color:#e2e2e2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    margin-top:1em;
    width:100%;
    padding:1em;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222222;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding-top: 1em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

footer h5 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

footer a {
    color: gray;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #ee6e73;
}

.input-field {
    margin-top: -1em;
}

.item {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 9px;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-right-color: #222222;
}

.item:last {
    border-right: none
}

.container .section h4 {
    padding-left: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;


.container .section p {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}
.col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.last {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "../includes/style.css";</style>
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="../" class="brand-logo">Home</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col s6">
        <h4>Welkom!</h4>
        <p>Heeft u nog geen account? Dan kunt u hieronder uzelf registreren door op de knop "Aanmelden" te klikken. Deze knop stuurt u door naar een pagina waar u uw gegevens kan invullen. Deze gegevens worden nagekeken door een administrator waarna u een
          activatiecode krijgt toegestuurd in uw mail. Deze code geeft u toegang tot de rest van het systeem!</p>
        <div class="row last">
          <div class="input-field s12">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Aanmelden
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col s6">
        <h4>Heb je al een account?</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
            <label for="email" data-error="Foutief e-mailadres!">E-mail</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row last">
          <div class="input-field s12">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Inloggen
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best solution is, add a class, and make the parent div relative, and the button position:absolute with bottom 0 or something and the parent a min height, easier way to handle this.

Comment: Firstly, you need to make the columns equal hieght. Your structure seems quite odd. I would not expect to see `.rows` inside `.col` divs.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make the columns equal height, flexbox can do that.

Then you need to push the buttons all the way to the bottom of the div. We can do that, again with flexbox but making each column a flex-container with `flex-direction:column` and selecting the last `.row` div (which holds the button) and giving it `margin-top:auto`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.last {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col s6">
        <h4>Welkom!</h4>
        <p>Heeft u nog geen account? Dan kunt u hieronder uzelf registreren door op de knop "Aanmelden" te klikken. Deze knop stuurt u door naar een pagina waar u uw gegevens kan invullen. Deze gegevens worden nagekeken door een administrator waarna u een
          activatiecode krijgt toegestuurd in uw mail. Deze code geeft u toegang tot de rest van het systeem!</p>
        <div class="row last">
          <div class="input-field s12">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Aanmelden
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" col s6">
        <h4>Heb je al een account?</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
            <label for="email" data-error="Foutief e-mailadres!">E-mail</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row last">
          <div class="input-field s12">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Inloggen
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rrdQNO)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. I've edited the existing post with new code. Maybe you see something that's wrong with it.